# How to get data to ViewModel list that is acquired from a service and then update the View?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a MVVM question.

I am successfully gathering data, creating an IoC container in my VM and binding it to my view. The issue I am having is that the view doesnt update its UI unless i navigate somewhere and then go back. Then the list is populated. See my logic below:

Service:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClassData> _MyList;
public ObservableCollection<ClassData> MyList
{
    get
    {
        return _MyList;
    }
    private set
    {
        _MyList = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MyList");
    }
}

async Task LoadData()
{
    var top = await cloudService.GetData().ConfigureAwait(false);
    MyList = top.results;
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public ObservableCollection<ClassData> MyList { get; }
```

VM (I do have a INotifyPropertyChanged in the VM as well, but do I need to use that in this example since its raisingpropertychanged from the service?):

```
 public ObservableCollection<ClassData> ViewModelList => this.service.MyList;

 private readonly IService service;
 public MyViewModel (IService service)
 {
   this.service = service;
 }
```

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource = {Binding ViewModelList} ... >
```

Comment: Try binding it via service `Binding Service.MyList` and raise property changed event for Service whenever it is changed.

Comment: Or you can attached an handler to service.PropertyChangedEventHandler and then raise notify change for `ViewModelList`
.

Comment: No success with `Binding Service.MyList`. If that would work, then it would for sure be the best solution. What do you mean with the 2nd option? If you could show an example that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "and raise property changed event for Service whenever it is changed. " - means to keep `MyList` just like it is in the example, correct? I have that right now but see no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Service.MyList}" />
```

ViewModel

```
private IService _service;
public IService Service
{
   get => _service;
   set
   {
       _service = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Service));
       // So whenever _service is changed, it will generate an event.
       // UI will get Service.MyList.
   }
}

// No Observable collection.
```

2nd Solution.

```
// When _service is changed.
_service.PropertyChanged += Service_PropertyChanged;
```

```
// Manually raise event to update list.
private void Service_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "MyList")
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ViewModelList));
}
```

Comment: Ok. I guess solution number 1 is best in terms of design? Then nothing has to be cleaned up on the viewmodel. And we can add idisposable on service